# chsh: Operation is not supported by the directory node when trying to change shell to zsh

Tags: shell, terminal, osx-lion, zsh

I'm trying to install zsh as my shell.

I've used curl to get the files.

```
curl -L https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/raw/master/tools/install.sh | sh
```

But when it gets to changing the shell it gives me...

```
chsh: Operation is not supported by the directory node.  Operation is not supported by the directory node. 
chsh: no changes made
```

Any ideas why this would be happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Change default shell from bash to zsh](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/88278/22781) at AD

Answer (score 0):

First thing would be to try changing the shell from your command line...

```
chsh -s `which zsh`
```

I have the following code to deal with a similar situation (not being able to change login shell at a work cluster). It starts zsh from bash, with some care taken about it ("works for me")

```
  # for hosts matching the silly name... start zsh from bash
  if [[ `uname -n` == foo-[0-9][0-9].bar.foobar.bar ]]; then
    if [[ -x `which --skip-alias zsh 2>/dev/null` ]]; then
        if [ -z $ZSH_STARTED ]; then
            export ZSH_STARTED="true"
            zsh
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Thanks but still get exactly the same response. Any other ideas?

Comment: then you likely can't change your login shell from this computer/host/node. That would normally be the case, when you have a central server controlling your identity (e.g. password, login shell etc), and you are trying to change it from a satellite. EIther that or the results of `which zsh` is not a valid shell. Normally the list of valid shells is at `/etc/shells`

Comment: Actually found a way that isn't even that complicated. I just created a .bash_profile file and added 'zsh' to it. So it runs every time when terminal starts and automatically loads zsh... lovely.